# Font Awesome not showing - Avada theme (Wordpress) - adding fa class

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

I migrated my wordpress site from a shared host to Digitalocean and everything went well except for the Font Awesome icons.

They are showing as blank squares on the live site.

I found the issue to be the required "fa" class for the icons is not showing up. I am using the Avada theme and am brand new to this.

1) I do not know where the CDN link is when I am searching through SFTP files. Can someone tell me where to find it so I can try to re-add the link.

2) Is there another way to automatically have the "fa" class to the icons so they will show up?

3) Any other insight into fixing the issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: hey - please accept the answer that I have give below, it has 2 upvotes, and answers your question - thank you

Comment: sorry for the delay. i was able to figure this out and forgot to check back on the answers. I accepted yours as the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() 
{
    // add this line
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    // Example styles and scripts
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

**alternatively** you can add this code to your header.php file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: I tried using the <link> option in header.php and that did not work.

I also tried the functions.php option and, unfortunately, I do not know where the directory is located to put that into the code.

Comment: I have added the code in `functions.php` and it worked for me. Thank You! `CodeBoyCode`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having this issue in Wordpress & Avada:

Have had this multiple times, this is how I solved it last time.

- Verify that the link is right, checking for typo's in the error link.
- Verify that the files of the error link are in place, also check if FTP rights are set right. (755 for folders, 644 for files)
- If the fonts still do not show, de-activate themes and plugins and re-activate them.

Comment: Wow nice thanks for adding this comment, I was stuck on this, then I just deactivated theme and re-activated and it kicked em back on

Answer (score 1):

Goto Avada -> Options -> Performance
Flush Avada cache

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue before, every time after migrating the website, the built in font awesome not showing at all, and display the square instead.

Then I go the "theme options" - click the "save" button directly, then hard refresh the page, everything will back to normal.

Or in some case, you need to double check the font awesome version from "theme features", turn on "Font Awesome v4 Compatibility" and turn off "Font Awesome Pro".

Hope that helps.